# Webpack. Set public path for images and fonts

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to fix an issue with my `assets`.
The problem is: I can get my picture or fonts using path: `/assets/img/*imgName*` and it's perfect in develop mode. But when I deploy my application, I want to add `somePath` before a path to picture or font. Like: `/*somePath*/assets/img/*imgName*/`.
I've done similar issue with js files using `publicPath`, and I know that if I use all my pictures inside JS files, I can add path (`somePath`) dynamically, but what can I do if I want to use this path inside `scss` files?

Thank you in advance.